# How do I remove focus from a TextField in SwiftUI on MacOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view in which the user enters data into a several textfields, but I can't allow the user to exit the textfields; one of them is always selected. How do I make the fields un-focus when I click on something else (the background, the submit button, etc.)?

Current View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
            TextField("Password", text: $password)

            Button("Submit") {
                // Submit data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an optional `@FocusState` and use `.allowsHitTesting(true)`. On the form, you put a `.onTapGesture` that sets `@FocusState` to nil.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: String?

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: "user")
            TextField("Password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: "password")
            Button("Submit") {
                // Submit data
                focusedField = nil
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            focusedField = nil
        }
    }
}
```

The `.allowsHitTesting(true)` lets the `TextFields` accept tap gestures directly, otherwise they would be blocked by the `Form's` `.onTapGesture`.

On macOS, in the sidebar, the form is only the size of the `Button` and `TextFields`. If you wanted a larger tap area, you would need some kind of background to place it on.

Comment: I'm getting an "Unknown attribute 'FocusState'" error... Is there a chance this solution only works for iOS? (I'm also on MacOS 11, but XCode doesn't mention anything about it being available in a future version of MacOS).

Comment: All of this is available to use on macOS, though I tested it on iOS. Let me run it through macOS.

Comment: Tested on macOS. No issue with using `@FocusState`. It actually takes a little less code than on iOS.